# HTML: Focus On Textbox When Page Loads

Tags: javascript, html

How do you focus on a text box when page loads? I have tried the autofocus attribute with no success.

Here's my form: http://pastebin.com/xMJfQkcs

Comment: `<input type="text" name="q" class="search_box" autofocus />`

Comment: In fairness, the OP did say he'd tried that. Though *not showing that attempt* seems a strange omission.

Comment: Give an ID to search input e.g. `id="search"` and then use this code JS `<script>document.getElementById('search').focus();</script>` or jQuery `<script>$('#search').focus();</script>`

Comment: @mdesdev: please don't recommend that; because this tends to lead to JavaScript stealing the focus from wherever the user *was* typing, and moving it somewhere else. It's never failed to irritate me. At least with HTML it seems to take into account whether the user has focused another input, or the browser's address-bar, to avoid that irritation.

Comment: I had no problems with autofocus, I used it a couple of times and when you focus out this script doesn't focus on again infinitely.

Comment: @mdesdev: the problem isn't infinite re-focusing; it's that the page partially loads, the user starts typing in whatever `input` field they choose (or the address bar), the page completes its loading, fires the `load`/`DOMContentReady` event and *then* the script steals focus and puts it into the designer-chosen `input` element and the user keeps typing, leading to two fields that have erroneous entries that need to be fixed.

Comment: @DavidThomas that's true.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? The autofocus attribute works on major browsers and IE10+. http://jsfiddle.net/zLLSf/

```
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus >
```